# Spring-Hibernate integration : Unable to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to use hibernate in spring framework.
Following are my files :

Employee.java :

```
package com.springstarter;

    public class Employee
    {
        private int id;

        private String name;

        private float salary;

        public Employee()
        {
        }

        public Employee( int id, String name, float salary )
        {
            super();
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId( int id )
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName( String name )
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public float getSalary()
        {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary( float salary )
        {
            this.salary = salary;
        }

    }

EmployeeDao.java

    package com.springstarter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;

    public class EmployeeDao
    {
        HibernateTemplate template;

        public void setTemplate( HibernateTemplate template )
        {
            this.template = template;
        }

        public void saveEmployee( Employee e )
        {
            template.save( e );
        }

        public void updateEmployee( Employee e )
        {
            template.update( e );
        }

        public void deleteEmployee( Employee e )
        {
            template.delete( e );
        }

        public Employee getById( int id )
        {
            Employee e = ( Employee ) template.get( Employee.class, id );
            return e;
        }

        public List<Employee> getEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            list = template.loadAll( Employee.class );
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Driver class :

```
package com.springstarter;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringORMApp
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "SpringStarter.xml" );
        EmployeeDao dao = ( EmployeeDao ) ctx.getBean( "edao" );
        System.out.println( ( ( Employee ) dao.getById( 1 ) ).getName() );
    }
}
```

Beans xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@[10.113.49.82]:1521:roc12c" />
        <property name="username" value="milli_sec" />
        <property name="password" value="milli_sec" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>employee.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="edao" class="com.springstarter.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

employee.hbm.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.springstarter.Employee" table="employee">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="name"></property>
        <property name="salary"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

[image]

No compilation issues.But expecting the employee object of id 1.
The following are the logs.

```
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:15 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:15 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:16 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: MILLI_SEC.EMPLOYEE
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, name, salary]
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [employee_pk]
Jan 28, 2016 4:28:46 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

Comment: Try changing this property `"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"` from `update` to `validate` or remove it at all. Also, make sure to catch any exception in your application and log it properly.

Comment: Pls provide complete log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the main issue that you don't use any transactions. For reading data with Hibernate you need transactions too. So you need to extend your `SpringStarter.xml` configuration with a transaction manager. You can use `@Transactional` annotation or add transactions to methods by methods masks in the `SpringStarter.xml`.

And there are some problems in your code

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate`

should be

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate`

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees()
{
    List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    list = template.loadAll( Employee.class );
    return list;
}
```

should be

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees()
{
    return template.loadAll( Employee.class );
}
```

and

```
HibernateTemplate template;
```

should be

```
private HibernateTemplate template;
```